# What can cause an unstable phugoid mode?

Tags: aircraft-design, stability, flight-dynamics

For clarity, I am wondering about how aircraft design can lead to the phugoid poles becoming complex with a positive real part, so an oscillation with increasing amplitudes.

My understanding of the phugoid is limited to the reduced order approximation, with the damping ratio being inversely proportional to the lift-to-drag ratio of the aeroplane. As such, I have difficulty understanding what could cause a negative damping ratio. Is there any derivatives in particular that can cause an unstable phugoid? Where is the energy for the increasing amplitudes coming from?

Comment: The [pilot itself](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot-induced_oscillation) can cause it or obviously some damage at the tailplane

Comment: @sophit With how long the period time of the phugoid typically is, PIO would have to be intentional, no? But, I was mostly wondering about ways aircraft design could create a naturally unstable phugoid. In what ways could a damaged tailplane cause an unstable phugoid?

Comment: Ah ok, you mean in the design phase. It's a very long mathematical story but the frequency of oscillation is mainly proportional to the inverse of the flying speed while the damping is mainly proportional to D/L. That implies that very efficient airplane (high L/D) flying at low speed (landing and taking off) might be problematic by a phugoid point of view. If this is what you're looking for I might elaborate it in a proper answer.

Comment: @sophit Yes, something akin to that is what I am looking for. I was aware of the approximations for the natural frequency and the damping ratio, but I don't understand how those can result in an unstable phugoid. Going by those, a high performance glider flying at low speeds should just result in a stable phugoid with very low damping and very high periods/very low frequencies, no? Does the approximation fail at those extremes or am I misunderstanding? I feel like I'm missing something and would be grateful for an answer.

Comment: Low speed implies high frequency (short period) and low damping, ideal conditions for PIO

Comment: @sophit Oh, you're right. I mixed those up. Low speeds means the phugoid mode has a high frequency. So it comes back to PIO? The phugoid doesn't become unstable without control inputs?

Comment: It might actually become unstable due to the thrust contribution but how exactly I don't remember  If you are not afraid of bug books with a lot of equation then "flight mechanics" is the keyword 

Comment: You have to differentiate between stick fixed and stick free no?  A divergent phugoid stick fixed would be pretty bad. Stick free, I used to fly a glider (LS-1) that had an all flying tail with no antiservo tab to provide restorative trim forces. All of the AOA seeking trim forces came from the trim bungee spring in the control circuit. Letting it fly hands off, it was divergent with maybe a 15-30 sec period. I never let it go long enough to see if it would stall or dive past Vne.  Hands on the stick, it was fine.

Comment: @JohnK and others -- I routinely experience "stick-free" divergent pitch phugoids in several different gliders; I put "stick-free" in quotes because my hands are off the stick but friction is clearly not letting the stick move completely freely.  Watching it, it tends to move some near the max and min airspeed points, and then to freeze again.  I have let the process continue to the point where there was a marked stall break at the low-speed end of the oscillation and quite a high airspeed at the high-speed end of the oscillation, sometimes approaching the maneuvering speed, and felt that...

Comment: ... and I felt that allowing the process to continue for a few more oscillations might indeed approach or exceed Vne.  A fun exercise is to get the oscillation going and then keeping hands off stick, try to use roll inputs (via the rudder pedals) to tame the oscillation-- it can be done, the trick is to try to have the bank angle shallowing (which tends to raise the nose above the horizon) at the same time that the airspeed is tending to increase, and try to have the bank angle increasing (which tends to lower the nose) at the same time that the airspeed is tending to decrease.

Comment: Gliders where I've seen these characteristics include Glassflugel 301 Libelle, and the lowly Schweizer 1-26.  As for true stick-fixed characteristics, I've found these hard to explore due to the difficulty of avoiding inadvertently avoiding making small pitch inputs.  Sometimes I've tried to do my best to accomplish that, and as far as I recall never had the impression that any initial pitch oscillation would not eventually damp out as the glider hunted for the "correct" aspd for the stick position-- at least so long as the first initial cycle didn't include a sharp stall break.